# IIS 7 - Windows 7 - WCF Random Timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I've run out of options at this point guys.  So here's the deal, up until today, I had a working setup on my work laptop.  I've built a web application using ASP.NET MVC and WCF.  My machine is Windows 7, I'm hosting the application on IIS7.

So, like I said, up until today the application worked fine.  Last night I installed windows updates.  After installing these updates, my WCF services are throwing timeout errors all over the place whenever multiple concurrent requests are made.

Before anyone asks, here are a list of things that I've investigated:

- There are no locks in the database.  As a matter of fact, at the time of the timeouts, there is no activity whatsoever in SQL server.
- The WCF proxies are being closed properly.
- I've uninstalled the windows updates in question.
- I've uninstalled the .NET Framework, as well as IIS and re-installed.

I've pretty much done everything short of wiping and re-installing Windows 7.

Also worth noting, is that the application works flawlessly in the QA and Production environments, as well as on other development machines.

Comment: Does the ServiceBehaviorAttribute allow concurrent connections?

Comment: You mean on the service class itself?  I don't have a ServiceBehaviorAttribute specified.  But again, it works fine everywhere but my local machine.  It has to be something with the way my machine or the application is configured on my machine.

Comment: Check if local ssms works fine? I know u checked for locks...

Comment: Yeah, there are no issues with the database.  This happens in an area where multiple concurrent requests can happen at once.  I'm wondering if it's a limit with Windows 7 Professional versus Server 2008 which is what our servers run.